# Add margin to a newcommand

Tags: macros, environments

I have a command that is defined like this :

```
\newcommand{\lol}[1]{\vspace{4pt}\color{subheadings}\raggedright\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg}\fontsize{9pt}{11pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont }
```

I want to add a margin to this command, but can't find a way to do so properly.

For the moment I am using the **scrextend** package like this :

```
\begin{addmargin}[2em]{0em}
\lol{MY TEXT HERE}
\end{addmargin}
```

But it is cumbersome to add the environment each time I use my *lol* command.

Is there a way to add the addmargin environment inside the newcommand definition ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like

```
\setlength{\leftskip}{2em}
```

or maybe

```
\addtolength{\leftskip}{2em}
```

if you want extra indentation in an already indented environment. But manipulating the internal variable `\leftskip` may be tricky because there can be unwanted interactions with LaTeX's environments.

The problem is, when do you reset the margin? The advantage of an environment is that it is clear when it ends, and moreover, the kind of definitions like the above automatically are undone at the end of the environment. Your command doesn't do that. So you would need another command to reset the margin.

Also another problem is that if you do this in the middle of a paragraph it will apply to the whole paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the effect of

```
\begin{addmargin}[2em]{0em}
\lol{MY TEXT HERE}
\end{addmargin}
```

the simplest way to do this is to modify your existing definition of `\lol` to include the `\begin`…`\end` of the enclosing environment. So you would rewrite your definition¹ as:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\lol}{m}{
  \begin{addmargin}[2em]{0em}
    \vspace{4pt}\color{subheadings}\raggedright\scshape\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Reg}\fontsize{9pt}{11pt}\selectfont {#1 \\} \normalfont 
  \end{addmargin}
}
```

---

1. Let's all get in the habit of using `\NewDocumentCommand` in place of `\newcommand`, OK?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, there are a few weak points in your definition of `\lol`:

1. the command should first do `\par`;
2. the `\color` statement should appear inside a group;
3. similarly for `\raggedright` and you *need* `\par` to end its effect;
4. using `\fontspec` in a document is discouraged, because it's very inefficient.

Now, unless you need lists or list based environments inside the argument to `\lol`, you don't need `addmargin`, but it's not a problem and it will provide the necessary grouping mentioned at points 2 and 3.

In the example below, I changed Lato to Fira Sans, because the Lato font in the standard distribution has no small caps. Also, `\lipsum` is used just to produce nonsense text. I added a definition for the color, use your own, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for text

\colorlet{subheadings}{green!30!blue}

\newfontfamily{\latofont}{Fira Sans} % my Lato font has no small caps

\newcommand{\lol}[1]{%
  \par
  \addvspace{4pt}%
  \begin{addmargin}[2em]{0pt}
  \color{subheadings}%
  \fontsize{9}{11}\scshape\latofont\raggedright
  #1\par
  \end{addmargin}
  \addvspace{4pt}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\lol{\lipsum[1][1-4]}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]